# Have to double tap for onClick calls of RecyclerView Item's TextView

Tags: android, android-fragments, adapter, onclicklistener, double-click

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `Fragment`. This `Fragment` is reused in multiple activities. I have setup a contract `interface` between my `Fragment` and the `RecyclerView.Adapter`. This contract does the following:

### Callback Interface

```
public interface TextViewClickListener {

    void onHandleClick();

}
```

In my Fragment I am implementing this listener like so:

### Fragment

```
public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment implements TextViewClickListener {

    // Initializing Code....
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, null);
        mRecyclerView = // Initialize 
        mAdapter.setClickListener(this);
        return root;
    }

    // Overriding listener
    @Override
    public void onHandleClick() {
        // Do something
    }

}
```

And inside my adapter I do the following:

### RecyclerView.Adapter

```
public class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private TextViewClickListener mClickListener;

    public void setClickListener(SampleFragment sampleFragment) {
        try {
            this.mClickListener = ((TextViewClickListener) sampleFragment);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // Print error
        }
    }

    // More initializing code

    public void onBindViewholder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        SampleViewHolder sampleVH = (SampleViewHolder) holder;
        sampleVH.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mClickListener.onHandleClick();
            }
        });

    }

    public class SampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    
        private TextView textView;

        public SampleViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            textView = // Initialize textview
        }

    }

}
```

My question is why does it take a double tap for the `onHandleClick` method to trigger in my `Fragment`, and how would I fix this?

#### I would like to make it so that a user just needs to tap the `TextView` once for `onHandleClick()` to trigger.

If this setup is too complicated is there an easier process, I am aware of `OnItemTouchListener()` for the `RecyclerView` and that wouldn't fit my usecase - I specifically would like click events to only be handles on certain parts of `ViewHolder`'s `View`.

**Update:**

I believe the issue might be that since there is an overall `View` for the `ViewHolder` I am assuming the `View.OnClickListener` is getting triggered for that `View` first then the `TextView`'s, i'll investigate this more.

Comment: Remove  android:focusableInTouchMode="true" and android:focusable="true" from layout that you inflated in adapter.

Comment: removing `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` did it for me